# How do I get an array of user roles to use in #options?

Tags: users, 8

Trying to convert my module to D8 and running into a problem using the D7: `user_roles()` function. Here's my D7 module code:

```
$form['role_vis_settings']['tynt_roles'] = array(
  '#type'          => 'checkboxes',
  '#title'         => t('Add tracking for specific roles'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('tynt_roles', array()),
  '#options'       => user_roles(),
  '#description'   => t('Add tracking only for the selected role(s). If none of the roles are selected, all users will be tracked. If a user has any of the roles checked, that user will be tracked.'),
);
```

And what I've got so far for D8:

```
$form['role_vis_settings']['tynt_roles'] = array(
  '#type'          => 'checkboxes',
  '#title'         => $this->t('Add tracking for specific roles'),
  '#default_value' => $settings['tynt_roles'],
  '#options'       => user_roles(),
  '#description'   => $this->t('Add tracking only for the selected role(s). If none of the roles are selected, all users will be tracked. If a user has any of the roles checked, that user will be tracked.'),
);
```

But get:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
```

I've looked at:

- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!src!Entity!User.php/function/User%3A%3AgetRoles/8
- https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!user.module/function/user_roles/8

The second was closet but not a format the `#options` array would allow (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/8#options).

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The first step is to enable error display, it is not possible to work otherwise. Read and follow the instructions in sites/example.settings.local.php. When you can see the error, you'll likely be able to figure it yourself. If not, post the error you get here.

Comment: I am closing this question since it doesn't show the error message. See the previous comment from @Berdir. We cannot know why you get _The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later._ since that could be caused from many factors. Notice that `user_roles()` still exists in Drupal 8, so it's not that function that causes the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct function name is:

```
user_role_names()
```

Comment: Actually, `user_roles()` is correct too, since it still exists in Drupal 8.

Comment: Nope, user_roels will give you objects, user_role_names will give you list of role names keyed by id.

Comment: It means the code needs to be changed, but the function is not wrong.

Comment: while converting module from d7 to d8 I struck with error Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Drupal\user\Entity\Role connot convert to string and d7 code was user_roles(). thx this helped.